# How can I graph a series of scores?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a score graph.  I have last seven scores of the game.  I could use the `graphics.lineTo` function but it takes so long.
Is there an easy way to do this ?

Example graph.

[image]

Here is what I tried so far. I made 20-40-60-80 lines movieclip and duplicate and change their name of each level.

```
                if(score1 == 40 && score2 == 20  && makeline == true){
        line20.x = 184;
        line20.y = 411;
        yirmiasah2 = true;//yirmi asa
    }
                    if(score1 == 40 && score2 == 40  && makeline == true){
        line40.x = 184;
        line40.y = 411;
    }
                        if(score1 == 40 && score2 == 60  && makeline == true){
        line60.x = 183;
        line60.y = 366;
    }
                                if(score1 == 40 && score2 == 80  && makeline == true){
        line80.x = 172;
        line80.y = 384;
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to create the blue graph line?

Comment: The easy way to do this is to use graphics.draw functions

Comment: "But it takes so long..."? What do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean it need making a graphic for each score.Let say score 2 = 80 and we know the previous score but where will the starting point of the second graph be? it's needed very much combination 20 to 80, 40 to 80,60 to 80.... .....

Comment: Use an array of points and loop through that array drawing the line to each point. It's pretty simple but I'm not sure what you are stuck on. Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not clear but you can try something like this.

Somewhere in your code you undoubtedly have a variable holding the score of the current game. You haven't shown that, so I'll call that current score from the last game `currentScore` of type `int`.  First this variable is declared outside of any functions.

```
var currentScore:int;
```

Then, while the game is being played, this value goes up whenever the player earns a point. In my example, he gets a point when Sprite A touches Sprite B

```
if (spriteA.hitTestObject(spriteB)){
    newScore++; // adds one to the newScore variable
}
```

Make an array to hold your scores in.  Put this outside of any functions. Putting it at the same place you put the currentScore variable makes sense.

```
var scoreArray:Array = new Array();
```

As each score is made final (at the end of a game), add that score to the array:

```
if (gameOver == true){
    // make a new variable to add to the array and give it the same value as the score of the last game
    var newScore:int = currentScore;

    // add the new variable to the array
    scoreArray.push(newScore);
    // this adds the newScore variable to the array.
    // after 7 games, you'll have 7 values in the array. 
}
```

Then to draw the graph:

```
var scoreGraph:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(scoreGraph);
scoreGraph.graphics.moveTo(0,100);
scoreGraph.graphics.lineStyle(1);
for (var i:int = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++){
    scoreGraph.graphics.lineTo(i*10,100-scoreArray[i]);
    // this will space out along the x axis by 10 pixels and put the x axis at 100 pixels down.
}
```

Comment: @KucuKeko you updated it. Ok. That's not an attempt to implement my method is it?

Comment: You have written a hand full of specific scenarios. What happens if score 1 is 23 and score 2 is 18?  Or if score 1 is 83 and score 2 is 85?  This not efficient to have to write every possible outcome. You need to learn how to write functions and pass them parameters. Please tell me what you don't understand about my method above. My 10 lines of code does 100x as much as your 100 lines of code can. Take the time to understand it.

Comment: Thanks.I trying to understand the system.push(newScore); // newScore function righ t? then what should I write to in ? All my score is numbers ( var number ) Should I use array anyway ?

Comment: An array can hold any type of value. The Array class has several methods (also known as function) which allow you to manipulate the array or the elements (values) in the array. One of these most commonly used methods/functions is `push();`.  `push` requires that you pass it a value (the things you want to add to the array). So `scoreArray.push(newScore)` will add `newScore` to the end of the `scoreArray` array. `newScore` would need be given a value prior to this example I posted.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify the .push part and to further explain some things. Look it over again. Try to understand it. Don't be afraid of google. Like searching for "what is an array" could have proved helpful, for example. But let me know if you get stuck again.